# ui:inputDateTime Icons Are Not Formatted Correctly - How to Fix?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datetime, lightning-design-system

When using the standard ui:inputDateTime component, I'm finding that the date and time picker icons are not formatted inside the field as expected:

[image: Image of date/time pickers outside of input field]

I'm using the following code (simplified for space):

```
<body>
  <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--x-large">
    <div class="myapp">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--5-of-6 slds-large-size--9-of-12">
          <div class="slds-grid slds-m-top--large">
            <div class="slds-col slds-col-rule--center slds-p-center--large slds-size--12-of-12">
              <article class="slds-card">
                <section class="slds-card__body">
                  <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--4-of-12">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-m-bottom--medium">
                      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Vendor Receipt Date/Time</span>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="start" class="slds-input"
                                        value="{!v.rmaWrapper.rma.RMA_Vendor_Receipt_Date__c}"
                                        displayDatePicker="true"
                                        labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-hint-parent slds-m-bottom--medium">
                      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Vendor Complete Date/Time</span>
                      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputDateTime aura:id="start" class="slds-input"
                                        value="{!v.rmaWrapper.rma.RMA_Vendor_Complete_Date__c}"
                                        displayDatePicker="true"
                                        labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong?I'm using force:slds in the app and I'm not using any custom css on this page. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add This code To css

```
.THIS .slds-input{
    margin: -15px !important;
}
.THIS .uiInput--datetime .timePicker-openIcon{
    left: 0px !important;
}
.THIS .uiInput--datetime .datePicker-openIcon{
    left: 0px !important;
}
.THIS .slds-card{
   padding: 15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `<ui:inputDate>`

Eventually I have solved it by inspecting the html class of the component =, and I found out it is `datePicker-openIcon`.

In my css file I have added:

```
.THIS .datePicker-openIcon{
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

And problem solved!!!

Do the same to your component, just find out first the class names

Comment: Unfortunately I added this to my css and saw no change :( Any other thoughts?

Comment: you need to investigate the component css attributes with the browser dev tools to see which css attribute is it you need to override

Comment: Apologies, I did not state in my comment that I had already done that. There are two fields, one for the date and one for the time. The classes are datePicker-openIcon and timePicker-openIcon respectively. This solution did not work when I used your solution. I'm wondering if there is something in the nesting I've done that is causing this answer to not work.

Comment: did you try to play with the size - 0px? by default for me this component was -22px and I played with the left attribute. try playing with it...

Answer (score 0):

Setting `width:95%` to `ui:inputDate` or `ui:inputDateTime` will fix the icon alignment issue.

**markup:**

```
<ui:inputDateTime value="{!v.dateTimeVal}" class="slds-input dateIconFix" displayDatePicker ="true"/>
```

**css:**

```
.THIS .dateIconFix{
    width:95% !important;
}
```